# display rows based on clicking on particular json array in nested ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, json

```
property  in homepalGroupProp.properties
```

my json data :

```
property=[{unitname : 1bhk, data:[{}]] }, {unit name : 3bhk},{}]
```

like this

```
{
    "UnitName": "3 BHK",
    "data": [
    {
        "UnitName": "3 BHK+3T",
        "property_size": "1521 ",
        "bedrooms": 3,
        "unit_type_name": "3 BHK",
        "unit_type_status": 1,
        "UnitPrice": 6538779,
        "price_per_sqft": "4299",
        "hp_property_id": 9,
        "unit_price_id": 51,
        "$$hashKey": "object:65"
    },
    {
        "UnitName": "3 BHK+3T",
        "property_size": "1523 ",
        "bedrooms": 3,
        "unit_type_name": "3 BHK",
        "unit_type_status": 1,
        "UnitPrice": 6547377,
        "price_per_sqft": "4299",
        "hp_property_id": 9,
        "unit_price_id": 52,
        "$$hashKey": "object:66"
    },
    {
        "UnitName": "3 BHK+3T",
        "property_size": "1525 ",
        "bedrooms": 3,
        "unit_type_name": "3 BHK",
        "unit_type_status": 1,
        "UnitPrice": 6555975,
        "price_per_sqft": "4299",
        "hp_property_id": 9,
        "unit_price_id": 53,
        "$$hashKey": "object:67"
    },
    {
        "UnitName": "3 BHK+3T",
        "property_size": "1526 ",
        "bedrooms": 3,
        "unit_type_name": "3 BHK",
        "unit_type_status": 1,
        "UnitPrice": 6560274,
        "price_per_sqft": "4299",
        "hp_property_id": 9,
        "unit_price_id": 54,
        "$$hashKey": "object:68"
    }
    ],
        "$$hashKey": "object:46"
}
```

my html code :

```
<div  ng-init ='homepalGroupProp.properties=hmpalprop(project.properties);'>


                                    <tr ng-repeat-start="property in homepalGroupProp.properties" ng-show="project.properties.length>3" ng-click="homepalGroupProp.expanded = !homepalGroupProp.expanded">
                                        <td ng-click="projectListingCluster(property.data,homepalGroupProp.expanded,$parent.$index,$index,property)">{{property.UnitName}}
                                            <span ng-if="!homepalGroupProp.expanded">
                                              <i class="fa fa-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                            </span></td>
                                        <td><span>{{}}</span></td>
                                        <td><span>{{property.price_per_sqft}}</span></td>
                                    </tr>

                                    <tr ng-if="homepalGroupProp.expanded" ng-repeat="prop in property.data" ng-repeat-end="">

                                        <td>{{prop.UnitName}}</td>
                                        <td>{{prop.UnitPrice}}</td>
                                        <td>{{}}</td>
                                    </tr>



                                </div>
```

controller code :

```
 $scope.projectListingCluster=function (p,ex,$index) {
     alert(ex +"..ex");
     alert(p+"..p");
     $scope.currentdata=p;
     alert(JSON.stringify($scope.currentdata));
     alert($index);
 }
```

i am getting loop is perfect but when i am clicking on first row like 1bhk.its opening all the rows.so i want to hide the two rows(2bhk,3bhk).if i clicked on two rows then its can show two rows.

[image]

[image]

Comment: have you tried using <tr ng-if="isComposite"> , with double quote "isComposite"

Comment: iscomposite is working but when iam looping with ng-repeat .its overriding the variable getting  true(if properties length <=3 ).see in controller code

Comment: i am failing in logic(not in code)

Comment: use ng-class="listclass", but i think you should add a new question for this, not modify the old.

Answer (score 1):

i think you need transform the properties json like this:

```
properties:[{
    UnitName:'3BHK',
    Items:[{as the property}, ...]
}, {UnitName:'', Items:[]}]
```

then nest two ng-repeater to archieve the target:

```
<tbody ng-repeat="group in properties">
    <tr>
        <td ng-click="expand">{{group.UnitName}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="item in Items" ng-show="Items.length<=3">
       <td>{{item.UnitName}}</td>
       ...
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 1):

you typo in your controller code

```
$scope.dummy = function(properties, $index) {
    proplength = properties.lengt
```

try this

```
$scope.dummy = function(properties, $index) {
    proplength = properties.length
```

hope can help you

Comment: getting that properties.length and loop index(0,1,2) based on this only . i can know the properties length in controller if properties length is less than  3 then i will assign the variable (iscomposite=false) .if iscomposite is false .then i below tr directly iterates.if  (properties length >3) its will show hide and show based on particular unit type under (1bhks,2bhks,3bhks) but in dummy function that iscomposite is getting (override) and ther is not getting link between the ng-repeat and iscomposite.i am facing major problem that one only

Comment: where dummy function call ?

Comment: at the start time of ngrepeat

Comment: when you call ng-init in start of ngrepeat , ng-init will be called once , so when ng-repeat do repeat ng-init doesn't call again.. 
you can call dummy function inside ng-repeat like this http://jsfiddle.net/fqnKt/37/
because you need compare each item

Comment: @SimhaChalam how ?

Comment: You ask here but you not appreciate any answer, you didn't admit when your code is wrong .. 
hmmmm